# mouseenter and mouseleave event not working on images which is blend

Tags: jquery

I have multiple images (created dynamically) in a div, I am applying mouseenter and mouseleave event for each image but its not working.

These images are blend image.

I want to display a cross button on image on mouseenter of image and hide cross button on mouseleave.

Below is my code  :

Created dynamic html like this and appended it into a div:

```
<img src='images/box_bg.png' id='img"+finaldivId+"'/><ImageButton id='close" +   finaldivId + "'>Delete</ImageButton>
```

Image blending code :

```
var id = "img" + finaldivId;
$('.ss-dragged-child img').blend({ id : id, mode: 'overlay', adjustment: 'rgb(' + colorArr.r + ',' + colorArr.g + ',' + colorArr.b + ')'});
```

Also I have returned img rather than canvas from blend.js and appended id in that img.

Below are mouseenter and mouseleave event on that img which is not working :

```
$('#img' + finaldivId).bind('mouseenter', function() {
     $("#close" + finaldivId).css({"display" : "block"});
});
$('#img' + finaldivId).bind('mouseleave', function() {
     $("#close" + finaldivId).css({"display" : "none"});
});
```

Kindly Suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use delegation **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** for dynamically appended html.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8DBqs/)

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','img[id^="img"]', function() {
     $(this).next().css({"display" : "block"});
});
$(document).on('mouseleave','img[id^="img"]', function() {
     $(this).next().css({"display" : "none"});
});
```

- `img[id^="img"]` checks img tags with Id - starting with 'img'.
- `$(this).next()` finds next element/child of only the current `<img>`.

If the ID selector is important,

You have to explicitly call the `bind()` event everytime your append.

Comment: Nope, its not working for me n id selector is importand bcz I have multiple images with different id like img1, img2, img3 and so on...

Comment: What is exactly not working? can you post a fiddle? The above code in generic and will word for all img-id's

Comment: It is not showing the close button on mouseenter on image.

Comment: I have 3 'p' tags on the image and while I mouse enter on that p elements the close button gets invisible. But I need to show close button at that time as well. What should I do ?